# PHP Facebook marketing api SDK without composer

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I've got a problem with the FB SDK install. I need to install the PHP SDK from FaceBook but my hosting provider doesnot allow to install composer. I heard there is another way to install the SDK without composer. Can you explain howto install the Facebook marketing API SDK. And if u can with example.

I need the info about my ads statistic via API to use it in my app. Maybe there is another solution for it withoit installation of SDK ?

Comment: Just download the zip and add it into your project manually:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/archive/master.zip

Comment: can u give me an example howto use it then?

Comment: why not use composer on your local machine to download all the dependencies, and then just upload that to your hosting provider?

Comment: very good idea. thanks. May be you know how to get accesstokens via api or something. I have access token only for a few hours and how can I use it in my app?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options :

**Option 1 :** You can install it locally using composer and then just transfer the files using FTP or file manager to your hosting environment.

**Option 2 :** Simple than that would be to copy the folder inside you app and then include files that are required. (I'd go with first option, as you'll get to learn about composer too).

One thing to understand is the source code(SDK) is just code, much similar to your app itself, and installing in composer just means composer will automatically include those files instead of you doing it.

If you need help installing on your local machine then here are some steps:

1. Install composer using [get composer](https://getcomposer.org/)
2. Install SDK using composer, i suppose you already know how
3. Make a zip and upload using FTP or Cpanel file manager or something similar

Hope this helps.